# timestamps and yahoo finance api

Tags: c#, timestamp, yahoo, yahoo-finance

I am having an issue with converting the timestamps that come from yahoo finance api to a DateTime in C#. I am trying to convert it like this:

```
    var _dt = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0).AddSeconds((Convert.ToInt32(timestamp))).ToLocalTime();
```

But I am thinking this is incorrect, I am comparing the closed prices with the times on google and they do not match up. an example of a timestamp would be:

```
    1453473058
```

and this would be converted to 1/22/2016 9:30:58AM. Thank you for your help, and if I am getting this right please tell me.

edit: I did find this code with visual basic to calculate the timestamps:

```
 Private Function Long2Date(lngDate As Long) As Date
     Long2Date = lngDate / 86400# + #1/1/1970#
 End Function

 Private Function TruncateSeconds(dateIn As Date) As Date
     TruncateSeconds = Int(dateIn * 1440) / 1440
 End Function
```

and then to get the final dateTime you do this:

```
 Dim long_TimeOnLine As Long: long_TimeOnLine = timestampValue - 14400
 Dim date_TimeOnLine As Date: date_TimeOnLine = TruncateSeconds(Long2Date(long_TimeOnLine))
```

Comment: Did you check the result of `_dt` I think that will be a great help :)

Comment: I use http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php and 1453473058 is converted to 01/23/2016@ 3:56pm (UTC), I think that the problem is "toLocalTime()".

Comment: yea I had the timestamp 1453473058 and it came out with 1/22/2016 9:30:58AM.

Comment: Are you getting the right timestamp without ToLocalTime()

Comment: I tried without the ToLocalTime and I get this for timestamp 1453473058, 1/22/2016 2:30:58PM. I am going to see if there is another way to do it.

Comment: Is that the right time? What should the right time be.

Comment: no it is not the right time, I am doing this with yahoo finanace and I am using stock GLNG, the timestamp is 1453473034 (the very first timestamp) and it is saying it is 1/22/2016 2:30:34PM, I lookup on google the close price for that time and it is 17.14, where the api data says it is 12.69. So in the timestamp is still not working.

Comment: You are converting a unix time to windows time.  The time is in UTF so you have use timezone indicate the time is UTF when converting.